# Topic/msg inspection tool

Tags: ros, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I am coming to ROS as an LCM user.  One of the LCM tools that I found very useful was lcm-spy (http://lcm.googlecode.com/svn/www/manpages/lcm-spy.html). The tool provided a complete high-level view of all published messages and the ability to drill down at examine the content of individual messages.

I have tried to replicate this functionality with various command-line options to rostopic without any luck.  My suspicion is that this tool exists.

Thank you,
Briani

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227825/topic/msg-inspection-tool./) by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the man page you link:

> lcm-spy collects the following statistics for each channel:

> - Channel name

This would be *topic* I guess in ROS: `rostopic list` / `rosservice list` (although those are not *channels*). If you want a GUI tool: `rqt_graph`.

> - Number of messages received

This is a bit trickier, and would need some bash scripting to keep a running total. Perhaps another member can suggest a suitable one-liner.

> - Message Rate (Hz)

```
rostopic hz /topic_name
```

> - Bandwidth (KB/s)

```
rostopic bw /topic_name
```

See also [wiki/rostopic](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic).

Note that these statistics are all relative to the start of a `rostopic` invocation.

You might also be interested in [wiki/Topics - Topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) and [rqt_graphprofiler](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graphprofiler).

---

Edit:

> [..] and examine the content of individual messages.

That would be `rostopic echo /topic_name`. Be aware that this can result in *a lot* of data for high-frequency / high-volume topics.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on 2016-03-16**:
Thank you for the recommendations.  It turns out what I was looking for was/is `rqt_topic`.  The other tools are useful.

Thank you!